# Functional root of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, functional-equations, wiener-measure

Does there exist a stochastic process $X$ such that when two such trajectories are sampled, their composition is Wiener-distributed? It would be natural to call such a process a functional square root of Wiener process, and take a look at some sampled trajectories.

A related question is: given a typical Wiener trajectory $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, does there exist $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g \circ g = f$?
It seems that a Wiener process is in some sense "compressing" the real line ($W(t) \approx \sqrt t$) so it is "very surjective" suggesting that the answer may be yes, but I don't know how to prove it.
Also, it seems that the asymptotics of such functions may be $t^{1/\sqrt2}$, as $(t^{1/\sqrt2})^{1/\sqrt2} = \sqrt t$.

P.S. Thanks to a comment by Ilya, indeed, I forgot to mention that I mean the two-sided Wiener process, so that a trajectory is a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R_{\geq0} \to \mathbb R$. This construction is also intuitive and translation-invariant, for example.

Comment: A typical Wiener trajectory actually goes $B(\omega): \Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R$. So if $B(\omega) = g\circ g$ then range of $g$ must be $\Bbb R_+$, hence so will be the case for $B(\omega)$, a probability of which I guess is $0$ or at least much less than $1$

Comment: I would imagine the approach would have to be looking at some of the pathwise properties...things like the law of iterated logarithm or quadratic variation converging to $t$